# KeyboardDatePicker change day and month to full length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JfMQ.png)

Hello,
is there any way to change Wed, Apr 7  to Wednesday, April 7 ?

To see day and month in full length not short format

Comment: can you please add the code where you use this component. Also list the library that you use for that component

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by making your own function. You can read about **Date and Time format in JS** by following this **[link](https://javascript.info/date#:%7E:text=The%20string%20format%20should%20be,is%20used%20as%20the%20delimiter.)**

Here is a simple example for the same.

```
let x = {};
x.longDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday'];
x.longMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

function getMyDate(myDate)
{
    return `${x.longDays[myDate.getDay()]}, ${x.longMonths[myDate.getMonth()]} ${myDate.getDate()}`
}

console.log(getMyDate(new Date()));
```

Comment: see please picture to understand what i need